# Getting objects from NSArray within another NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray

for an iOS 5.0 application using ARC, i have an NSArray of objects that contain NSArray of other objects within it. Is it possible to extract a list of objects from inner arrays without iterating through the Array e.g. say, with NSpredicate or valueForKeyPath. To be clearer, I have:

```
NSArray *objtype1 contains
         -id
         -NSArray *imageObjs containing imageObjects
                       -imagetype = 1 <--1st imageObject
                        imageURL1 
                       -imagetype = 2 <--2nd imageObject
                        imageURL2
         -NSArray *objtype2 
         -other parameters
```

I need to extract the NSArray of imageType = 1 imageObjects to pass in for further processing. Is this possible? (I'm looking at NSpredicate, and valueForKeyPath, but have not found anything yet)

Comment: It looks like rather than a parent array, you really want to make this a class with properties of id, nsarray, nsarray and other parameters.

Comment: I agree with @sosborn. When you have a data structure that does not easily fit into the NS classes then just make your own. Give it a nice clean interface and then you won't be littering code all over the shop for accessing the properties of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you haven't found anything yet is because it's not there. You could implement your own category on `NSArray` to use predicates recursively. Perhaps someone else have done it already. I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Ummmmm it seems a bit unclear as to what you are doing. It looks like you have an NSArray of multiple types. And you want the imageObjs array inside it.

If you infact have an NSArray like this, it would be monumentally easier to convert it to an NSDictionary. Then you can use `[dictionary valueForKey:@"Image Array"];` to get the image array out of it.

Currently, your solution to get the imageObjs array would be `[objtype1 objectAtIndex:1];` then iterate over that array to use the imageObjects in it.

```
for(ImageObject *obj in arr) {
    //do stuff
}
```